# How to create a SnoreToast start menu shortcut with a Working Directory to a .BAT file?

Tags: node.js, windows, batch-file, path, shortcut-file

Using node-notifier@7.0.0's SnoreToast on NodeJS v13.13.0, I am trying to create a Start Menu shortcut to use as appID for SnoreToast's notifications, I have a .BAT file that runs the command `node "src\index.js"`, and I'm assigning this .BAT file as the target application of the SnoreToast shortcut as seen below:

```
"..\node_modules\node-notifier\vendor\snoreToast\snoreToast-x64.exe" -install "SomeAppName\SomeAppName" "c:\Users\Redacted\Desktop\proj\start.bat" "app.someappname"
```

The shortcut is successfully installed on the Start Menu in a folder named SomeAppName and the shortcut itself named SomeAppName aswell, and when I open the shortcut, it targets the correct start.bat file, but the start.bat is unable to fullfill it's purpose due to the shortcut opening it on `C:/WINDOWS/System32` and ultimately wrongly targets `C:/WINDOWS/System32/src/index.js`, causing it to fail.

By manually editing the shortcut's "Start in" option on the Properties dialog in File Explorer to the correct path of my project (`C:/Users/Redacted/Desktop/proj`) and saving, it runs perfectly, but obviously I don't want to make my users have to manually do this work + the application should be portable and runnable anywhere it's stored on the FS, so how would I edit the "Start in" (aka Working Directory) of a SnoreToast shortcut on creation? I've already tried to Google it but all the results are unrelated and SnoreToast's documentation doesn't address this issue either.

A solution that does not require any additional npm packages would be preferred, but one that uses an npm package is acceptable aswell. All help is appreciated.